# Shorten Selenium-Wire Option

Tags: python, selenium

I would like to improve the following case by shorting it. I've come this far

```
if decision == 'y':
    seleniumwire_options = {
        'proxy': {
            'http': f'https://usr:pw@page:port',
        }
    }

if decision == 'n':
    seleniumwire_options = {
        'proxy': {
            'no_proxy': 'localhost,127.0.0.1'
        }
    }
```

You could say that I should just remove the `n` decision, but I can't because I need `seleniumwire_options` later.

```
webdriver.Chrome(..., seleniumwire_options = seleniumwire_options)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can shorten it by factoring out common parts, like this:

```py
if decision == 'y':
    proxy = {
        'http': f'https://usr:pw@page:port',
    }

if decision == 'n':
    proxy = {
        'no_proxy': 'localhost,127.0.0.1',
    }


seleniumwire_options = {
    'proxy': proxy
}
```